# Finding set of products formed by two lists

Tags: algorithm, list, performance, runtime

Given two lists, say A = [1, 3, 2, 7] and B = [2, 3, 6, 3]

Find set of all products that can be formed by multiplying a number in A with a number in B. (By set, I mean I do not want duplicates). I looking for the fastest running time possible. **Hash functions are not allowed**.

First approach would be brute force, where the we multiple every number from A with every number in B and if we find a product that is not already in the list, then add it to the list. Finding all possible products will cost `O(n^2)` and to verify if the product is already present in the list, it will cost me `O(n^2)`. So the total comes to `O(n^4)`.

I am looking to optimize this solution. First thing that comes to my mind is to remove duplicates in list B. In my example, I have 3 as a duplicate. I do not need to compute the product of all elements from A with the duplicate 3 again. But this doesn't still help reducing the overall runtime though.

I am guessing the fastest possible run time can be `O(n^2)` if all the numbers in A and B combined are unique AND prime. That way it is guaranteed that there will be no duplicates and I do not need to verify if my product is already present in the list. So I am thinking if we can pre-process our input list such that it will guarantee unique product values (One way to pre-process is to remove duplicates in list B like I mentioned above).

Is this possible in `O(n^2)` time and will it make a difference if I only care about the number of unique possible products instead of the actual products?

```
for i = 1 to A.length:
    for j = 1 to B.length:
        if (A[i] * B[j]) not already present in list: \\ takes O(n^2) time to verify this
            Add (A[i] * B[j]) to list
        end if
    end for
end for

print list
```

Expected result for the above input: 2, 3, 6, 9, 18, 4, 12, 14, 21, 42

## EDIT:

I can think of a `O(n^2 log n)` solution:

1) I generate all possible product values without worrying about duplicates \ This is `O(n^2)`

2) Sort these product values \ this will be `O(n^2 log n)` because we have n^2 numbers to sort

3) Remove the duplicates in linear time since the elements are now sorted

Comment: "if all the numbers in A and B combined are unique. That way it is guaranteed that there will be no duplicates", this is not true, all numbers from A and B combined would have to be unique AND prime numbers

Comment: @FrançoisHuppé Omg yes, you are correct. if A = [4, 6, 10]  -  B = [8, 20] then (4, 20) and (10, 8) is 80. I will edit my post. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You could use binary search trees/b-trees (some languages like Rust already have b-tree based set structures in the standard library) to bring the lookup time down to `log n` to make your overall algorithm `n^2 log n`.

Comment: @EvilTak If I want overall ```n^2 log n``` I can also think of a simpler way without using tress? I have edited my post with that solution in the end. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Venkatesh the sorting solution works too, you can use either.

Comment: At least, it's brought down to ```O(n^2 log n)``` from ```O(n^4)``` . Thanks for the tip. I am thinking if we can do any better at all!

Comment: If you have a set data structure then duplicates will be elminated automatically. You said hash map isn't allowed, but nothing about hash set.

Comment: @maraca I understand that hash set eliminates duplicates automatically. I actually meant it as a list, and not as a hash set though. Sorry for the confusion, I edited my post.

Comment: Well then I think you already have the best possible time complexity, except if you would use something like radix sort (guess number of bits is constant, because you deal with int or long), so time complexity of the sort would be O(n^2) and overall time complexity is O(n^2) too, which is obviously the best one you can achieve.

Comment: @maraca Oh wow, yes I didn’t think about radix sort. Nice, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Use sets to eliminate duplicates.

```
    A=[3, 6, 6, 8]
    B=[7, 8, 56, 3, 2, 8]
    setA = set(A)
    setB = set(B)
    prod=set()  #empty set

    [prod.add(i*j) for i in setA for j in setB]
    print(prod)
    {64, 448, 6, 168, 9, 42, 12, 16, 48, 18, 336, 21, 24, 56}
```

Complexity is O(n^2).

Another way is the following.
O(n^3) complexity

```
 prod=[]
    A=[1,2,2,3]
    B=[5,6,6,7]

    for i in A:
              for j in B:
                  if prod==[]:
                      prod.append(i*j)
                      continue
                  for k in range(len(prod)):
                    if i*j < prod[k]:
                     prod.insert(k,i*j)
                     break
                    elif i*j == prod[k]:
                     break
                    if k==len(prod)-1:
                     prod.append(i*j)
    print(prod)
```

Yet another way. This could be using hash functions internally.

```
   from toolz import unique
    A=[1,2,2,3]
    B=[5,5,7,8]
    print(list(unique([i*j for i in A for j in B])))
```

Comment: I think Set is an interface? You will need to implement something like HashSet for your solution and in my algorithm, hash functions are not allowed!

Comment: Where have I used hash functions? Set is an abstract data structure. How is it an interface?

Comment: In Java, Set is an interface. I looked up how Set in python works internally and it uses hash tables.

Comment: Added to previous answer